# How to check more detailed information on a wireless network?

Tags: wireless-networking

When I connect to a wireless network from my computer, I can see the current PHY layer speed and signal stress in the adapter status.

How can I see more detailed configure like current MIMO stream count, channel number, channel width, the broadcasted capability from AP, etc?

I cannot find them any where on Windows and Linux (iwconfig).

Do I need a third party tool to do that?

Comment: Maybe Nirsoft's [WifiInfoView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html) suits your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Linux, the `iw` commands to get current information are mostly

```
iw wlan0 link
iw wlan0 station dump
```

and

```
iw wlan0 scan dump
```

for information about the APs, including capabilities. `iw` replaces the older `iwconfig`.

I'm not aware of any way to get current MIMO stream count, or channel width, though you can infer them from the transfer speed to some degree. AFAIK there isn't a standardized API to get this kind of information, so unless you hack your driver, even a third party tool won't get them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is everything you are after, but iwlist wlan0 scanning will provide more detailed information about the available AP's (indeed iwlist shows quite a bit with other options - iwlist --help will show more info on the tool).

Likewise iw --help will give you info on what another tool can do (and, for example, "iw list" will provide details on what your device supports

Comment: `iwlist` is going to be fairly limited (the WEXT api is stuck in the past decade) – you'll likely need `iw` to see anything like MIMO.